# .htaccess rewrite rule Case inSensitive/ Ignore case in urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my URL for URL incase sensivity i.e. to convert url tolowercase

> (**eg. www.MywebsIte.Com/Abc should be redirected to
>   www.mywebsitename.com/abc**)

I have found may suggestion but all keep on giving me server 500 error refer code below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} !^www.mywebsitename.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsitename.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The above code works perfectly fine.
Need to add code/rule for URL case insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Add this rule in your htaccess

```
CheckCaseOnly On
```

This will affect all levels in the URL, for example http://localhost/ExAmPle/someFILE would be fixed to http://localhost/example/someFile

Comment: Sorry this might be very silly but please tell me where should i place that statement in my code... I don't have any clue about URL rewriting...

Comment: you can place it in the last line before <IfModule>